# Placing a gameobject with restrictions

Tags: unity, c#

I am newbie in programming and I am making a tower defense game 2d. My problem is I want to make a restriction to place a tower only, if the mother tower is in place or within its range. I'm sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing. For example, you can oly place a certain tower within the range of the mother tower and only if that mother tower is placed. I don't exctly know if I have to create a function for this or create a range game object for the placement attached to the mother tower. Any help and tips would be appreciated, thank you. This is by the way unity C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple!  All you have to do is, first to find the mother tower by name by going `GameObject mother = Find("Mother")` or whatever you call it. 
 Check `if (mother != null)`, and if so take the Euclidean distance between the mother's Vector2 and the tower's Vector2 like `Vector2.Distance(mother.transform, tower.transform)` (assuming you have tower defined as another GameObject for your tower.

All together now:

```
GameObject mother = Find("Mother");
if (mother != null) {
    if (Vector2.Distance(Input.mousePosition, mother.transform.position) < 20) { // replace that with your range
        // place your tower on click
    } else
        print("Too far m8");
} else
    print("Build a mother first m8");
```

Comment: @Kram Yup!! Good luck on your future endeavours :D

Comment: Just don't call `GameObject.Find()` inside `Update()`, it's expensive.

Comment: @Draco18s Ahhh yes totally forgot.  Call Find() in Start() not Update().  Sorry... I didn't really test this out cuz I was busy

Comment: No worries, Daneolog, I make that comment on a lot of posts, just so that future readers know of the pitfall. Speaking of, do you know how Camera.main works? `GameObject.FindObjectWithTag()` and it doesn't cache the results. Know what happens when you have a canvas object with no camera set? It uses `Camera.main`...